# can I use the following formula for polar coordinates as well?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Simpl asking, can I use the following formula for $\theta$ as we always do for an argument of a complex number $z=a+bi~$:

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}(b/a),~~a>0;~~~ \theta=\pi+\tan^{-1}(b/a),~~a<0$$

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: so there is no difference between them? Thanks